# merge JSON objects recursively

Tags: json, go

Here's an example of what I need:

Default JSON:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "greetings": {
        "first": "hi",
        "second": "hello"
    }
}
```

merged with the changes:

```
{
    "name": "Jane",
    "greetings": {
        "first": "hey"
    }
}
```

should become:

```
{
    "name": "Jane",
    "greetings": {
        "first": "hey",
        "second": "hello"
    }
}
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func MergeJSON(defaultJSON, changedJSON string) string {
    var defaultJSONDecoded map[string]interface{}
    defaultJSONUnmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(defaultJSON), &defaultJSONDecoded)
    if defaultJSONUnmarshalErr != nil {
        panic("Error unmarshalling first JSON")
    }
    var changedJSONDecoded map[string]interface{}
    changedJSONUnmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(changedJSON), &changedJSONDecoded)
    if changedJSONUnmarshalErr != nil {
        panic("Error unmarshalling second JSON")
    }
    for key, _ := range defaultJSONDecoded {
        checkKeyBeforeMerging(key, defaultJSONDecoded[key], changedJSONDecoded[key], changedJSONDecoded)
    }
    mergedJSON, mergedJSONErr := json.Marshal(changedJSONDecoded)
    if mergedJSONErr != nil {
        panic("Error marshalling merging JSON")
    }
    return string(mergedJSON)
}

func checkKeyBeforeMerging(key string, defaultMap interface{}, changedMap interface{}, finalMap map[string]interface{}) {
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(defaultMap, changedMap) {
        switch defaultMap.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            //Check that the changed map value doesn't contain this map at all and is nil
            if changedMap == nil {
                finalMap[key] = defaultMap
            } else if _, ok := changedMap.(map[string]interface{}); ok { //Check that the changed map value is also a map[string]interface
                defaultMapRef := defaultMap.(map[string]interface{})
                changedMapRef := changedMap.(map[string]interface{})
                for newKey, _ := range defaultMapRef {
                    checkKeyBeforeMerging(newKey, defaultMapRef[newKey], changedMapRef[newKey], finalMap)
                }
            }
        default:
            //Check if the value was set, otherwise set it
            if changedMap == nil {
                finalMap[key] = defaultMap
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    defaultJSON := `{"name":"John","greetings":{"first":"hi","second":"hello"}}`
    changedJSON := `{"name":"Jane","greetings":{"first":"hey"}}`
    mergedJSON := MergeJSON(defaultJSON, changedJSON)
    fmt.Println(mergedJSON)
}
```

The code above returns the following:

```
{
    "greetings": {
        "first": "hey"
    },
    "name": "Jane",
    "second": "hello"
}
```

So basically any changes should be applied to the default and return the full JSON. I also need this to work recursively.

How can I fix this? I can see where I went wrong, I'm just not sure how to make it work recursively.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far and what issues you're having with it?

Comment: Updated the post with an example of what I have so far. Basically it works perfectly fine except when it has to work recursively. I was hoping there was a Go package out there that would do this already, but I couldn't find anything that did this.

Comment: There is no stdlib package that does this as a single operation, and requests for third-party libraries are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Is the JSON in a well-defined format or do you need to do this for any arbitrary JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue in the posted code is with your recursive call:

```
checkKeyBeforeMerging(newKey, defaultMapRef[newKey], changedMapRef[newKey], finalMap)
```

The reference to `finalMap` should actually be the nested part of the merged map. Meaning replace `finalMap` with something like `finalMap[key].(map[string]interface{})`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently come across the same need, here is my solution:

```
// override common json by input json
func Override(input, common interface{}) {
    switch inputData := input.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        switch commonData := common.(type) {
        case []interface{}:
            for idx, v := range inputData {
                Override(v, commonData[idx])
            }
        }
    case map[string]interface{}:
        switch commonData := common.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            for k, v := range commonData {
                switch reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() {
                case reflect.Slice, reflect.Map:
                    Override(inputData[k], v)
                default:
                    // do simply replacement for primitive type
                    _, ok := inputData[k]
                    if !ok {
                        inputData[k] = v
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return
}
```

unmarshal json before call:

```
var commmon interface{}
if err = json.Unmarshal("common data", &commmon); err != nil {
    logger.Error(err)
    return
}

var input interface{}
if err = json.Unmarshal("input data", &input); err != nil {
    logger.Error(err)
    return
}

Override(input, commmon)
```